# How do I compile and install the latest PiTiVi 0.15.2?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, compiling, pitivi

As there's a critical bug in PiTiVi 0.15.1 (version released in Software Center) and I need to finish a project, I tried to install the latest version, 0.15.2. I tried to add the PPA and to compile it (I found the instructions at the [PiTiVi website](http://www.pitivi.org/?go=download)), but I had no luck. What should I do?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 in an iMac 21'5'' Late 2009.

Comment: If its in a PPA, it shouldn't need compiling. If you are compiling the source from the website, please post errors, warnings, etc.

Comment: No, I tried to install the PPA 'and' to compile the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PPA does not include any packages for Precise (12.04), and contains no packages for the version you want either (0.15.2), so it's useless. You can remove it from Software Center or using `apt-add-repository`.

0.15.2 compiled just fine for me on Precise 64-bit, with the following. Open a terminal, and run the following to install PiTiVi 0.15.2 on your system

```
sudo apt-get build-dep pitivi -y
sudo wget -O- http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pitivi/0.15/pitivi-0.15.2.tar.xz | tar -xJ
cd pitivi-0.15.2
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Try `sudo apt-get update` to update your package list.
2. Then `sudo apt-get autoclean` to cleanup any partial packages.
3. Then `sudo apt-get clean` to clean up the apt cache.
4. Then `sudo apt-get autoremove` to cleanup any unneeded dependencies
5. Then run `sudo apt-get install -f`
6. Then run `sudo apt-get update`

Now go to the Ubuntu Software Center and remove the PiTiVi ppa which is noted as *ppa:gstreamer-developers*

Now install the PiTiVi by running the following commands one at a time:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa && sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install pitivi`

The whole process should remove all the previously installed broken packages and do a fresh install.

Comment: The PPA doesn't contain packages for Precise and in any case, contains no packages for the version the OP wants (0.15.2).